# Write LS command just using system-calls without using any library-calls of C

Tags: c, linux, terminal, command-line-arguments, system-calls

**ltrace myls** should give output with no library calls.
I wish to implement ls with -(paramenters) too and directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getdents(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getdents), the low-level Linux system call for reading a directory. Make sure you read the **Notes** section: you have to use `syscall` to call this, there's no library wrapper. The **Example** there is a simple `ls` program that uses it.